# Blueimp File Upload works but files aren't sent

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to customize Fileupload basic plugin, but i've stuck at the beginning. I use the example html from [basic plugin example page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) with only changed urls:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="upload" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It looks like all working, but files aren't uploading: there are no files in destination folder and x-debug shows that $_FILES is fully empty -- it doesn't even contains 'files' key.

I've tested it in different browsers -- result is the same.

I've also looked in developer tools. After each try to upload console says:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/j3/fu/upload".
```

But looking in Network tab shows that GET requests are always sent, so i think that is the problem.

```
GET /j3/fu/upload/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.48
Referer: http://localhost/j3/fu/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: currency=USD; area_unit=sqm; b0b171866a6ab587715b9e92d420ca7c=97pi1htvn8vb6j16smtnuslh65; dd66659b0452c6865c97fbf5cf8960e2=58evm1pql2jqsi6pj34a9842p7; XDEBUG_SESSION=netbeans-xdebug
```

I've tried to set 'type' to 'post' in options, and also tried to set data-type="post" in my input element, but it didn't worked.

So does anyone know what can be done to this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Just after reading my own question, i've guessed about solution, and it worked! So, the solution is use *upload/index.php* instead of just *upload*

Comment: Marked an answer also.